# Show that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is not differentiable at the origin.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

This is very simple but I am having some trouble. Please indicate whether my proof is correct.

We want to show that $f(x, y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Is not differentiable at the origin. If it was differentiable, the partial derivatives at the origin would exist. However, for example,

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h,0) - f(0, 0)}{h} = \frac{|h|}{h} = 
\begin{cases}
1, \quad \text{ if } h \to 0^+ \\
-1, \quad \text{ if } h \to 0^-
\end{cases}
$$
and hence the partial derivatives fail to exist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What trouble are you having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Or you can say that the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}g\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R^2\\&x&\mapsto&(x,0)\end{array}$$is differentiable at $0$, that $g(0)=(0,0)$, but that $f\circ g$ is not differentiable at $0$ ($f\circ g$ is the absolute value function).

Comment: I have solved similar problem over here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3554607/determine-whether-fx-y-sqrtxy-and-or-gx-y-ex3y-are-differenti/3554638#3554638. You con use the same technique in this case also.